# String and int memory address in PHP

Tags: php

I am studying PHP, and I find, if use `===` to compare the variable:

```
<?php 

    $x = "100";
    $y = 100;
    var_dump($x===$y);  // print bool(false)
?>
```

But if I use the below:

```
<?php 

    $x = "100";
    $y = '100';
    var_dump($x===$y);  // print bool(true)
?>
```

So, someone can explain why it return false and true in the example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `===` compares the variable type and the value. In example one you have a string against an integer, these don't match. Example two you have a string against a string, these match.

See: https://3v4l.org/Jgohi4

For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

Comment: does this related to memory address?

Comment: What is the question?